# react native "this.setState is not a function" error inside componentDidMount method after firebase login

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Can anybody tell me why I am getting this.setState is not defined error in the code below?

```
componentDidMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            this.setState({user:user});
            console.log(user.uid);
        } else {
            this.setState({user:null});
            console.log("logged out");
        }
      });
}
```

I tried different approaches also:

```
componentDidMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            //this.setState({user:user});
            this.sState(user);
            console.log(user.uid);
        } else {
            this.setState({user:null});
            console.log("logged out");
        }
      });
}
sState(user){
    this.setState({user:user});
}
```

For the above, the error is **this.sState is not a function**.

I checked out the similar questions in SO they don't seem to be helpful in my case.
Thanks..

Comment: Can you show the whole react component? It looks that the problem might be somewhere else than in your snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use Arrow functions or bind the onAuthStageChanged to the components

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        //this.setState({user:user});
        this.sState(user);
        console.log(user.uid);
    } else {
        this.setState({user:null});
        console.log("logged out");
    }
});
```

Arrow functions bind automatically to this, normal functions does not

[Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable)

**EDIT**
Using bind over a function. Basically when the function is called, assigns 'this' operator to the bind argument.

```
componentDidMount(){
    firebase
       .auth()
       .onAuthStateChanged(this.authStateChangeHandler.bind(this));
}

authStateChangeHandler(user) {
    if (user) {
        this.setState({user:user});
        console.log(user.uid);
     } else {
        this.setState({user:null});
        console.log("logged out");
     }
}
```

Comment: this seems to work. thanks, @jgoday. Can you also add the code snippet for the part you say "or bind the onAuthStageChanged to the components"? How do we do that exactly? how do I achieve this without the arrow function?

Comment: thanks for the edit. Now I realize that when we bind a method with .bind(this), we don't need to explicitly pass an argument to the bound function (in this case authStateChangeHandler) but it automatically gains access to the returned user object from firebase. How would you explain this?